# Using ng-model to insert data into arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm rendering the contents of an array using ng-repeat like this-

```
    <tr  ng-repeat="option in eventCtrl.questionDetail.options track by $index">
           <th scope="row">Option {{$index + 1}}</th>
                <td>
                     <input type="text" ng-model="option" ng-change="eventCtrl.newlyAddedOptions[$index] = option" style="width:100%;">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure to delete?" confirmed-click="eventCtrl.removeOption($index)" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Delete</button>
                </td>
       </tr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" ng-click="eventCtrl.addOption()" id="addNewOption">+ Add New Answer Option</button>
```

On click of the button I'm insering an empty string into the questionDetail.options array so that I get an empty input field to insert my data.Controller functions looks like this-

```
myApp.controller('eventController',function(){
     let dash=this;
     dash.newOption ='';
     //store all newoptions to this array before finally updating the 
     //question
     dash.newlyAddedOptions = [];
     dash.addOption = () =>{
         dash.questionDetail.options.push(dash.newOption);
     });
         //add new options 
dash.updateTheQuestion = () =>{
  //add the newly added options in the questionDetail if any which will be finally updated
apiService.updatequestion(dash.params.qid,dash.questionDetail).then(function successCallBack(response) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
            alert(response.data.message);
        });
    }
```

Now when I insert data into the field and try to add another option the previously inserted field becomes blank beacuse the `questionDetail.options` array get rerendered again.However I've used `ng-change` to collect data and store it into the newlyAddedOptions array.

**How do I change the empty strings pushed into array with the value that is retrieved with `ng-model="option"` so that I could directly push those into `questionDetal.options` array.**

I know this good be done easily and I'm missing something.
Thank You in advance.

**Edit**:I was pushing an empty string because I wanted a blank input on clicking the add option where I can insert new option.This is mainly the edit question view where user can add an option or delete an option with the options that are coming from the database.

Plunkr-https://plnkr.co/edit/SLfy8qaz8LoHurwpVmw6?p=catalogue

Comment: Can you create a plunkr and share it. Your question isnt much clear. Eg:   Why would **questionDetail.options array get rerendered again** happen ? Share an example

Comment: When you click on the button, you push a new entry into the array. Good. Now, where would be the desired text and what should the text be? In the new record? If yes, why don't you simply add it before or after the `push`?

Comment: Also, show how you are updating `dash.newOption` before pushing to array. I think you are doing it wrong. And **dont use ng-change** as it'll push everytime you press any `char` from keyboard

Comment: Not sure this is the issue, but still... Replace `dash.questionDetail.options.push(dash.newOption);` with `dash.questionDetail.options.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dash.newOption)));`. This is just a test...

Comment: @ShashankVivek The questionDetail.options array get rerendered again due to addition of the empty string.

Comment: plz add a small plunkr demo, you'll get your solution in few mins.

Comment: @ShashankVivek please check this...I want to replace the empty strings with the input typed....open the console in code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxvdwX?editors=1011

Comment: Use indexing to store with ng-model

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali I already tried it with $index but not able to do.Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<tr  ng-repeat="opt in eventCtrl.questionDetail.options track by $index">
               <th scope="row">Option {{$index + 1}}</th>
                    <td>
                         <input type="text" ng-model="newlyAddedOptions[$index]"  style="width:100%;">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure to delete?" confirmed-click="eventCtrl.removeOption($index)" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Delete</button>
                    </td>
           </tr>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" ng-click="eventCtrl.addOption()" id="addNewOption">+ Add New Answer Option</button>
```

https://codepen.io/supravi96/pen/bMmpOQ?editors=1010

Comment: firstly with eventCtrl.newlyAddedOptions[$index] will always by undefined , as you are accessing an index of an array which doesnt exists , so you need to push the value instead of assigning , hence put it on ng-click . And also the key name and ng-model name was named same as option so the value of ng-model was always undefined .

Comment: How will I get the option as it is outside the ng-repeat.

Comment: You should be able to access it with $scope. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrVzdg?editors=1010

Comment: getting undefined  values in the array.

Comment: You can try the above link , it should definitely work now .

Comment: @supravi you removed ng-model="option" ,so how would I render the options from the eventCtrl.questionDetail.options array

Comment: Werent you trying to access the option values from newlyAddedOptions?? will you elaborate on how exactly do you to get the output ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171159/discussion-between-supravi-and-rahul-jhawar).